# REACT Router v6 not triggering useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

The useEffect function is not triggering in AddFarm.js path

AddFarm.js - Path: /anadir-granja

```
    const fetchData = async()=>{
        console.log("fetchdata")
        try{
            const res = await axios.get("link")
            console.log(res)
        }catch(error){
            console.log(error)
        }

    }

    useEffect = (() =>{
        console.log("useEffect")
        fetchData()
    }, [])
```

App.js

```
return (
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={<Home/>}/>
        <Route exact path="anadir-granja" element={<AddFarm/>}/>
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
```

I want to have a web with many paths where each path is a component. I want to call the useEffect function to fetch data from a mongodb on each component.

Comment: I don't see any overt issue with this specific code. Can you [edit] the post to include a more complete [mcve] and provide more details on the specific issue, like what are the exact reproduction steps it takes to cause the issue to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `AddFarm` component is not mounted when you go to this path `/anadir-granja` and the reason is you forgot to put a `/` before `anadir-granja` in the `path` property of the `Route` component. It should be like this:

```
<Route exact path="/anadir-granja" element={<AddFarm/>}/>
```